# CNN for regression problems using image statistical features as inputs

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a [17000 obs,72 statistical features] dataset of sky images, and I want to train a CNN for regression problem (sky image --> irradiance) in matlab but I don't know how. Since I don't have statistical features as input rather than pixels of images, all solutions in the documentation do not help. Is there any other solution I can try? FYI: I've only turned to deep learning because standard neural networks were giving me a bit high error values.. Thank you for your time